# cannot convert from from entity framework to system.data.objects.objectcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nsmanagedobjectcontext

iam trying to retrieve multiple non-entity objects from a database i'm using EF5, and on coding the following

```
   using (FluoraPinEntities context = new FluoraPinEntities()) {

                string mQuery = @"select EMAIL,FIRST_NAME,USER_ID from USERS where EMAIL=\'" + mail + "\'";
                foreach (DbDataRecord rec in new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(mQuery, context))
                {
                    string x = rec[0].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("ID {0}; Name {1}", rec[0], rec[1]);
                }
            }
```

i get the following errorcannot convert from from entity framework to
1- system.data.objects.objectcontext

Comment: Is this the exact exception message?

Comment: it's not exception , it's syntax error :D and yes it's the same syntax error  .